# How to run query without running out of disk space in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am running a query that is giving me issues at as little as 20k rows of data. Though I should mention that I am doing 9 Left Joins. I get the following error:

```
ORA-27061: waiting for async I/Os failed
Linux-x86_64 Error: 28: No space left on device
```

I have 40gb of disk space so this is confusing. I have also mounted an external disk with 800 gb of space. How can I circumvent this issue?

Comment: A dritical disk partition on your database server is at or nearly full - mot likely the partition storing your TEMP tablespace data files. With that many joins you are likely using a at least some TEMP space to create intermediate data sets or perform sorts. Is your database using ASM storage or file system storage?

Comment: Are you sure that your join conditions are valid, and not leading to cartesian oroducts? you haven't shared your queries

Comment: is the db on your workstation?  If not, then this has nothing to do with sql developer client-side software.